# Include email address in reply_header_authorwrote

Tags: thunderbird

I have Icedove (Thunderbird) 17.0.9. When I reply to an email, the following gets added infront of the original email:

```
On 2013-11-28 19:05, John Smith wrote:
```

in my config editor, I have

```
mailnews.reply_header_authorwrote    "%s wrote"
```

But I would like to have the email address included as well, ie:

```
On 2013-11-28 19:05, John Smith <joh@smith.com> wrote:
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

The Thunderbird add-on [SmartTemplate4](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/smarttemplate4/?src=ss), currently version 0.9.4, can customize the reply header
to anything at all.

See the [Support site](http://smarttemplate4.mozdev.org/) for more information.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this without any addon? Can I just edit/add some parameter in `Config editor` or in `prefs.js` ?

Comment: That configuration is controlled by [mailnews.reply_header_authorwrote](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Mailnews.reply_header_*), where its default is `%s wrote` and
%s is replaced with the author's name (or e-mail address). Another [forum thread](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=643230), although from 2008, confirms that "This is currently hardwired in the code, the "%s" is the only parameter accepted". So I myself am rather convinced that the only solution is using an add-on.

Comment: And the reply header is very, very, very customizable with this add-on. (running it now with `Op %X:=sent%%e% %B% %Y%, %from(name)% <%from(mail)%> schreef:` for dutch). And hey... what's the use of add-ons if you're not going to use them :)

Comment: Why should I install a several-thousand-lines-of-code addon, just to change few characters in the email header? Seems like overkill to me.

Comment: Because there is no other way. Adding such an option in Thunderbird itself would cost these same several-thousand-lines-of-code, but in Thunderbird.